# create dynamic mat-table like math matrix with angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, mat-table

I have one  problem on create table. My struct data is dynamic,that means number of row and column is variable like matrix `m*n`. and struct is available on [here](https://fuzzyitem.free.beeceptor.com/).
[image]

I want to show `json (above photo)` to **mat-table**.but I can't correctly assign data to table and it show Duplicate data on table.show `column0` for all rows of mat-table.

[image]

while Correct data in table should be
[image]

My code is available on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-achc6e).

in this code,i want create table with `5` col and `6` row.

**how can i  solve it and show all data in this table?**

Answer (score 1):

when you has a matrix you has a FormArray of FormArrays,e.g. If you has a data like

```
export const data=[['uno','one'],['dos','two'],['tres','three']]
```

You can format a formArray of FormArray like (**)

```
  myformArray = new FormArray(
        data.map(row=>new FormArray(
            row.map(x=>new FormControl(x))
  )))
```

When you use a mat table you need a 'displayedColumns', an array with the columns you want display. If you want has a button "delete", you can use another variable more

```
  displayedHeads: string[] = data[0].map((x,index)=>'col'+index);
  displayedColumns: string[] = this.displayedHeads.concat('delete')
```

Well, It's close to be ready, I added a new variable more that indicate the number of columns you has -this allow us add a new row-, and the table using viewChild

```
  columns: number = data[0].length;
  @ViewChild(MatTable, { static: true }) table: MatTable<any>;
```

Our table it's ready to show it:

```
<button mat-button (click)="add()">Add row</button>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="myformArray.controls" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container *ngFor="let head of displayedHeads;let j=index" [matColumnDef]="head">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{head}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <input [formControl]="element.at(j)">
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index;">
      <button mat-button (click)="delete(i)">delete</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

See that the dataSource is `myformArray.controls` and in the input is `[formControl]="element.at(j)`, yes "element is the inner formArray"

You can see the example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-knrn22?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html) (*)

I add two functions to add and remove row

```
  delete(index: number) {
    this.myformArray.removeAt(index);
    this.table.renderRows()

  }
  add() {
    const empty = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.columns; i++)
      empty.push(true)

    this.myformArray.push(
      new FormArray(empty.map(x => new FormControl('')))
    )
    this.table.renderRows()

  }
```

(*) In the stackblitz I added a directive to allow move across cells using arrows keys

(**) In your case you format the form Array as

```
myformArray = new FormArray(
        data.map(row=>new FormArray(
            row.map(x=>new FormControl(x.c))
  )))
```