# How can I create a Matrix in Angular which uses the same Row & Column titles and has binding check boxes?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am struggling to think of or find a solution for this (fairly common) scenario:

**Pre-req:** Users have the ability to define a heading.

**Outcome:** Foreach heading, it will create a row & column in a table (of the defined heading) where the cell value will be a checkbox.

```
#    Test1|Test2|Test3
Test1  x
Test2        x    x
Test3             x
```

---

I need to be able to track that `[1,1].value = true` and `[2,1].value = false` etc.

As this is a POC I can hardcode the data I need for now.

My first thought was to create a Matrix Object which stored: `RowData`(`name` & `position`), `ColumnData` (`name` & `columnPosition`) and had `value` and `position` (takes row & column data position and combines).

---

**HTML**:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="weightMatrix" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="#">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.row}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of weightingComponents" [matColumnDef]="column.name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column.name}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="element.value"> </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

--

**TS**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WeightingComponent } from '../weighting/weighting.component';

export class TableMatrix {
  rowTable: WeightingComponent;
  columnTable: WeightingComponent;
  position: any[];
  value: boolean = false;

  constructor(x: WeightingComponent, y: WeightingComponent) {
    this.rowTable = x;
    this.columnTable = y;
    this.position = [x.position, y.position];
  }
}

const SET_RULES_POC: any[] =
  [
    'Test1',
    'Test2',
    'Test3',
  ];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-component',
  templateUrl: './table-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-component.scss'],
})


export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() weightingComponents: WeightingComponent[] = []

  @Input() weightMatrix: TableMatrix[] = [];
  displayedColumns: any[] = [];

  rules = SET_RULES_POC;
  public constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rules.length; i++) {
      this.weightingComponents.push(new WeightingComponent(this.rules[i], i));
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.weightingComponents.length; i++) {

      for (let j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {

        let x = this.weightingComponents[i];
        let y = this.weightingComponents[j];

        let matrix = new TableMatrix(x, y);
        if (!this.weightMatrix?.includes(matrix)) {
          this.weightMatrix?.push(matrix);
        }
      }
    }
    this.weightMatrix
    SET_RULES_POC.unshift('#');
    this.displayedColumns = SET_RULES_POC;

    console.log(this.displayedColumns);

  }

  public doStuff() {
    console.log(this.weightMatrix);
  }

  public getPosition(x: any, y: any) {
    return [this.weightMatrix[x].position, this.weightMatrix[y].position];

  }
}
```

My issue is:

1. The checkboxes are all linked, when i select one, they're all updated
2. I cannot seem to get the first Column defined by the same as the row

Please bear in mind this is my first Angular project and as a POC I haven't followed best practices

Comment: some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59223972/create-dynamic-mat-table-like-math-matrix-with-angular-material/59234386#59234386)?

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo, I did see this already but unfortunately isn't what I am after.

Comment: Can you recreate your issue with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) please, it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `new Map()` to store the array as a key like this,

```
handleClick(val) {
    if (this.result.has(val)) {
      this.result.delete(val);
    } else {
      this.result.set(val, 1);
    }
  }

  res() {
    console.log(this.result.keys()); // Iterate through the selected keys
  }
```

[Code sandbox demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-water-2kls5b?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Upvote if it's helpful.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! So simple as well... knew I was being slow :)

Answer (score 0):

If i got everything correctly, you should do two-way-binding with the data from the matrix. When you generate the input you bind the value of the cell to the checked attribute and not to the value, and then use the indexes on the onChange function like this:

```
(onChange)="myHandler($event, x,y)
```

then you can update the matrix like this:

```
public myHandler($event, x,y){
    M[x,y]=$event.checked;
}
```